# Python relative import reexport

Tags: python-3.x

I am writing a python package that I intend to use for some projects I am working on. I do not want this package to be in a public package index, so I am currently using `git submodules` to easily set it up in projects. Every import inside the package is relative.

My package's structure looks like this:

```
package
|---__init__.py
|---src
    |---__init__.py
    |---core
        |---__init__.py
        |---types.py
        |---interfaces.py
|---test
```

I want to make some modules more accessible, so the top level `__init__.py` file of my package has some lines like this:

```py
from .src.core import types
from .src.core import interfaces
```

### The problem

I place the python package somewhere in my project:

```
project
|---__init__.py
|---main.py
|---package
```

in the main file, i can do the following:

```py
from package import types

def foo(param: types.Foo):
    ...
```

but I want to do:

```py
from package.types import Foo # raises ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package.types'
```

I can't find the reason why this happens nor how to solve it. I don't want to publish the package to a public package index and I doubt I can get access to a private one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've gone through python's import system documentation and found out the root of the issue. Altough `package.types` is a module, it is not a direct reference to a module, but rather to the `types` object from `package`. This means that it can only be accessed after `package` is explicitly imported.

Knowing this, the solution is quite simple: create a `types.py` python file inside package that contains the reexports.

First, add a types.py file in the top level directory of the package:

```
package
|---__init__.py
|---types.py <-- add this
|---src
    |---__init__.py
    |---core
        |---__init__.py
        |---types.py
        |---interfaces.py
|---test
```

Then, the `types.py` file imports the types I want to reexport:

```
from src.core.types import Foo
```

Now the types can be accessed both ways:

```py
from package import types

def foo(param: types.Foo):
    ...
```

```py
from package.types import Foo

def foo(param: Foo):
    ...
```